# Wacom tablet pen tips

Tags: adobe-photoshop, tablet

I bought an Intuos 3 6x8 several years ago but do not use it much, primarily because I have found it difficult to adapt to the pen. I would appreciate advice on how to deal with this issue: as I bring the pen in close proximity to the tablet, I see the cursor and move the pen to make the cursor go to the coordinates I am interested in. But when I bring the pen down further to click on that point, I frequently find myself having to move the pen down further than I anticipate, and in that zone I often end up clicking on another point than the one I want. Is there some sort of proximity adjustment that will help me with this, as I would like to use the tablet more.

Someone suggested this link, which is helpful but does not directly address my question:
http://psd.tutsplus.com/articles/theory/break-in-your-new-tablet/

Comment: What problem specifically is this causing with your photographs and/or camera?

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't a photography related question.

Comment: I've checked with the Super User mods and it's on-topic over there. Don't repost, but flag this question for migration.

Comment: this is strange, I have the cheap Wacom Bamboo Pen and use it in GIMP without such problems. But according to me it works better with Win XP than 7.

Comment: If Photoshop is photography-related, then this question is also photography-related because it deals with tools used to edit photographs in Photoshop. Or are you saying that Photoshop questions are not photography-related?

Comment: @WarrenKeuffel: Were saying that the question as posed is more about tablets than photography, and tablets are NOT on topic. When it comes to the nature of on and off topic here, were not looking for "by the letter"...were looking for "by the spirit". Just because something has a tangential relationship to photography does not mean it IS ABOUT photography.

Comment: Were happy to have to contribute as a member of our community, however arguing like you have about the fact that your question is on-topic because its about photoshop and since photoshop is (sometimes) about photography, so is your question...well thats just argumentative, and doesn't help anyone. I'm going to close this question, since it is most assuredly about the Intuos 3 tablet, and not about photography, regardless of any second-degree relationship because your using the tablet with photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

Running the pen is like riding a bike. You're at the "still in need of training wheels" stage (not intended as flippant), and it can be frustrating, I know.

These is no adjustment on the Wacom's proximity sensing, but you will find that if you spend the time to practice with the pen, really making yourself use it for a bit, you'll build the necessary hand-eye coordination into your visual and muscle memory. After that, you won't think about it any more until you're on a forum like this and someone asks, "I bought an Intuos 3...". Take it from one who has been there. :)